# Azure Batch Pool

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I am creating a custom activity pipeline in Azure Data Factory and as a part of that I need to create an AzureBatchLinkedService using the JSON below:

```
{
    "name": "AzureBatchLinkedService",
    "properties": {
        "hubName": "name_hub",
        "type": "AzureBatch",
        "typeProperties": {
            "accountName": "accountname",
            "accessKey": "**********",
            "poolName": "?????????",
            "batchUri": "https://northeurope.batch.azure.com",
            "linkedServiceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService"
        }
    }
}
```

When I created this the first time, I didn't have to create a batch pool. It was created for me automatically
[image]

My question is how do I get Azure to create this "pool" for me? If I go into the batch account and click "Add+" to add a pool manually, it has all these config options and I don't know what to put for any of those fields.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to create the batch pool yourself? Is Azure Data Factory creating it for you a problem?

Comment: No, I would like it to create it for me, but it's not doing that

Comment: Ah I see, would you prefer help diagnosing what data factory isn't creating the pool for you automatically or help creating one by hand? If so, could you document what steps you are taking on the 2nd attempt, are you creating a new linked service for example or are you creating a new data factory?

Comment: I hadn't created a data factory / batch linked service by hand for a while; you're correct you need to create the pool by hand. Though I'm not sure if that has always been the case (I can't remember), this guide shows you some example values for batch pool setup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities